# Applications of differential equations in Business

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently doing some independent research on applications of ODE in business. I am asking some opinions to where you may find ODE's being used in Business.

I know for example Finance is a big one especially figuring out how annuity may accrue over a time (t). The (Pert) formula I know stems from ODE's.

Does anyone know if ODE's can be applied to economics or supply chain/inventory?